# How to compare non-nested models (with different number of items) in CFA?

Tags: r, model-comparison, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I investigate the factor structur of an existing scale in a data set with N = 714 (using lavaan, R). In this context I would like to compare to alternative models:
Model 1: Two factors with 5 items each and in addition one item that is allowed to load on both factors (11 items)
Model 2: Two factors with 5 items each without the additional item (10 items).
For the "standard indices" the following results are obtained:

```
Model 1: RMSEA=0.135 [0.125; 0.145], SRMR=0.059, CFI=0.871, TLI=0.831, AIC=18633.493, BIC=18743.194
Model 2: RMSEA=0.141 [0.130; 0.153], SRMR=0.058, CFI=0.875, TLI=0.834, AIC=16891.818, BIC=16987.807
```

(As you can see the fit for both models is not very good. As I found out thanks to you ([CFA lavaan - reasons for bad fit?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380121/cfa-lavaan-reasons-for-bad-fit)) this is due to a number of correlated errors, which may be caused by the formulation of questions and dependencies between questions. If I include these correlated errors in the model (which I know to be considered with caution for various reasons and therefore I'm still undecided how to handle it) the fit improves clearly. With correlated errors, model 2 **seems** superior to model 1 in terms of all indices)
But after further reading, I don’t think it’s appropriate to use these indices to compare my models, i.e. **non nested models with different numbers of items** (even though I've seen it in literature several times). Finally I came across the vuong-test and got the following results:

```
Model 1 
 Class: lavaan 
 Call: lavaan::lavaan(model = m1, data = data.set, model.type = "cfa", ...

Model 2 
 Class: lavaan 
 Call: lavaan::lavaan(model = m2, data = data.set, model.type = "cfa", ...

Variance test 
  H0: Model 1 and Model 2 are indistinguishable 
  H1: Model 1 and Model 2 are distinguishable 
    w2 = 0.559,   p = 1.8e-09

Non-nested likelihood ratio test 
  H0: Model fits are equal for the focal population 
  H1A: Model 1 fits better than Model 2 
    z = -132.171,   p = 1
  H1B: Model 2 fits better than Model 1 
    z = -132.171,   p = < 2.2e-16

Model 1 
 Class: lavaan 
 Call: lavaan::lavaan(model = m1, data = data.set, model.type = "cfa", ...
 AIC: 25452.965 
 BIC: 25562.666 

Model 2 
 Class: lavaan 
 Call: lavaan::lavaan(model = m2, data = data.set, model.type = "cfa", ...
 AIC: 20167.351 
 BIC: 20263.340 

95% Confidence Interval of AIC difference (AICdiff = AIC1 - AIC2) 
  5207.322 < AICdiff < 5363.905

95% Confidence Interval of BIC difference (BICdiff = BIC1 - BIC2) 
  5221.035 < BICdiff < 5377.617
```

Do you think that in this case the vuong-test is actually a reasonable way to compare the models? The extreme p-values appear suspicious... And if no, what could you possibly recommend to me?